# async/await Model View Presenter winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have a winforms app that is using the MVP pattern as described in this post
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563809/UIplusDesignplusUsingplusModel-View-Presenter I am converting my app to async/await but am having issues.

Here is an example to illustrate my issue

```
public interface IView
{
    event Action DoSomething;
}

public partial class MyForm : Form, IView
{
    public event Action DoSomething;

    public MyForm() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OnSomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DoSomething!= null)
        {
            try
            {
                await DoSomething();
                SomeOtherMethod();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }   
    }
}

public class MyPresenter
{
    private readonly IView _view;
    private ClassWithAwaitbleMethods _foo;

    public MyPresenter(IView view)
    {
        _view = view;

        _view.DoSomething += OnDoSomething;
        _foo = new ClassWithAwaitableMethods();
    }

    public async void OnDoSomething()
    {
        //this may throw an exception
        await _foo.SomeAwaitableWork1();
    }
}

public class MySecondPresenter
{
    private readonly IView _view;
    private ClassWithAwaitbleMethods _foo;

    public MySecondPresenter(IView view)
    {
        _view = view;

        _view.DoSomething += OnDoSomething;
        _foo = new AnotherClassWithAwaitableMethods();
    }

    public async void OnDoSomething()
    {
        //this may throw an exception
        await _foo.SomeAwaitableWork2();
    }
}
```

This code is not awaiting properly and when an exception is thrown it is not caught. This is because of async void. When this code was not async/await exceptions were caught fine.

I know async void is a no no except for top level events but the way my app is designed I can't really get around that. When I only had one subscriber I changed the IView interface to

```
public interface IView
{
    Func<Task> DoSomething {get; set;};
}
```

and wired things up like this

```
public MyPresenter(IView view)
{
        _view = view;
        _view.DoSomething = OnDoSomething;
        _foo = new ClassWithAwaitableMethods();
}
```

Which is hacky but awaits things properly and catches exceptions.
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what "not awaiting properly" means? Async void methods can't handle exceptions with a try/catch (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) why not just return a `Task` (not `Task<T>`) instead?

Comment: It shouldn't be any code change other than saying `private async Task` instead of `private async void`, see also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is that the code is using events as a strategy pattern rather than an observer pattern. There isn't much you can do with this code as it currently stands; a proper refactoring would require callback interfaces rather than events. E.g.:

```
// An instance of this is passed into the concrete view.
public interface IViewImplementation
{
  void DoSomething();
  // Or the async equivalent:
  //   Task DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

However, there are some workarounds you can apply, if that level of refactoring is unsavory. I cover such ["async events"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) on my blog. There are a few approaches; it is possible (though awkward) to define a `Task`-returning event. My favorite approach, though, is Deferrals, mainly because deferrals are a concept already familiar to WinRT developers.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for answering my question so quickly. I will look into using deferrals. I would like to refactor the code but I don't understand your proposed solution to refactor.
I would like the work to be done in the presentation layer, and when the view fires off DoSomething() I would like to have multiple presenters that get passed a the view interface do different work.

Comment: @jeffreyk: The idea behind the refactoring is to have a callback interface instead of an event. So it's a more explicit kind of subscribe/publish.

Comment: Hey Stephen, I got your book and am using deferrals as described in it. The problem I am having is with exceptions. If an exception is thrown in the handler of the async event (for example is the first line of the using block that gets the deferral), it is not caught in the try catch where the event is being raised. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if what I am trying to achieve is just not possible.

Comment: @jeffreyk: Exceptions raised from `async void` methods cannot be caught (at least, not easily). They'll be raised on the current `SynchronizationContext`. If you need that kind of behavior, you should really define a visitor interface with a `Task`-returning handler instead of (ab)using events, as I described in my original answer.